# How to load images in an ImageSwitcher from server?

Tags: android, thread-safety, imageswitcher

I m trying to load images in an image switcher from Http server. I didnot find any function like setImageBitmap. So I tried using setImageURI() , but its not getting loaded.
I am tring to switch image after every 3 sec. This is the code. When i m running the codes image is not getting loaded. And app is also getting crased.

```
 String arr[]={"http://192.168.1.7/photos/dummy/1.jpg","http://192.168.1.7/photos/dummy/2.jpg","http://192.168.1.7/photos/dummy/3.jpg"}


 dailyWear = (ImageSwitcher) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageDailyWear);
dailyWear.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView myView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return myView;
        }
    });
    dailyWear.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
    dailyWear.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right));

 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        int i=0;
        public void run() {
            weddingWear.setImageURI(Uri.parse(arr[i));

            i++;
            if (i >= arr.length()-1)
                i = 0;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is first get these images and store it in arraylist of bitmap that you can switch these images

```
private Context mContext;
private int index = 0;
private final int interval = 3000;
private final int DURATION=1500;


  public void animate_Images_In_Top_View_After_Every_Three_Seconds(
        ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher, final ArrayList<Bitmap> _Images_List) {

    android.view.animation.Animation aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
    aniIn.setDuration(DURATION);
    android.view.animation.Animation aniOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);
    aniOut.setDuration(DURATION);

    final ImageSwitcher _ImageSwitcher = imageSwitcher;
    _ImageSwitcher.setInAnimation(aniIn);
    _ImageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(aniOut);
    _ImageSwitcher.setFactory((android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory) mContext);
    _ImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(_Images_List.get(index)));
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                index++;
                index = index % _Images_List.size();
          //      Log.d("Intro Screen", "Change Image " + index);
                _ImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(_Images_List.get(index)));
                handler.postDelayed(this, interval);

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
}
```

and i am using fade in and out animation you can set to your own need.

Comment: its working fine but, just one problem. Suppose in the bitmap array size is 3 , then after sliding three image one after another. its wating another 3 sec without any image, then again its starting from 0 ,meaning it circulating but a 3 sec gap is coming in between.